# Desperate for help showing integral is analytic

Tags: real-analysis

I don't have a prodigious background in analysis and would like some help...
Is the integral
$$f(t) = \int_{1}^{t}\sqrt{s} ds$$
analytic?

Clearly, the places where $\sqrt{s}$ fails to be analytic (i.e., the origin) are excluded from the region of integration...if it is analytic, why? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you exclued the origin, that's easy; at any positive number, there is a Taylor series expansion that converges by the Taylor remainder theorem, so it is analytic (you can also use the binomial series, appropriately shifted). Then integrating preserves analyticity.